# NodeJs Application need guide in implementing php as template

Tags: node.js, express

Can anyone please guide me through to implement PHP as template for NodeJS application.
I am planning to use :
PHP to load only the front-end html template (security purpose)
ExpressJs as my backend.

I got struck in implementing the same here i am attaching the code below :

```
var phpnode = require("php-node");
app.engine('php', phpnode);
app.set('view engine', 'php');
```

and I am trying to load template like this :

```
router.get('/index.php', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index.php');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal example:

File structure:

1. ./test.js - our nodejs file
2. ./php/ - our view folder with php files
3. ./php/phpinfo.php - our test php file

./test.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    //make sure that `bin` location is right for you system
    phpnode = require('php-node')({bin:"/usr/local/bin/php"});

app.set('views', __dirname+'/php/');
app.engine('php', phpnode);
app.set('view engine', 'php');

app.all('/phpinfo.php', function(req, res) {
   res.render('phpinfo');
})

var port = process.env.PORT || 8081;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
})
```

./php/phpinfo.php

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

The open http://127.0.0.1:8081/phpinfo.php in your browser, you should see phpinfo text output (not a HTML, plain text, because php we ran in a CLI mode, exactly like if you ran it in terminal)

Tell me if you need it not in a CLI mode, I'll try to find out how to switch it..

Comment: I have tried the above settings                                                                
      Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory 
      "/node_app/firstApp/templates/"

Comment: I got the above error I have all the template in templates directory

Comment: Ok, give me a minute, I'll write for you minimal sample

Comment: Ok, I think i am missing something in the settings.

Comment: Thanks dude it worked, I missed the path for php-node.